# HBM Hibernate many-to-many bidirectional connection with extra column

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, hbm

i googled a lot and did follow many tutorials about it, but i didnt get it to work. I have a many-to-many relation between the table Player and Type. Both tables are connected via typeperplayer. In the table typeperplayer is an additional column paid, which i want to use in hibernate.

Here is the database scheme:

### Player:

Play_ID : int

Play_FirstName : string

Play_LastName : string

### Typeperplayer:

Typl_ID : int

Typl_Play_ID : int

Typl_Type_ID : int

Typl_Paid : int

### Type

Type_ID : int

Type_Name : string

Here is my Hibernate-Mapping:
**Player:**

```
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="de.tt.treg.server.domain.Player" table="player">
    <id name="id" type="java.lang.Integer">
        <column name="Play_ID" />
        <generator class="identity" />
    </id>
    <property name="firstName" type="string">
        <column name="Play_FirstName" length="255" not-null="false" unique="false" />
    </property>
    <property name="lastName" type="string">
        <column name="Play_LastName" length="255" not-null="false" unique="false" />
    </property>
    <set name="competitions" table="typeperplayer"
            inverse="true" lazy="false" fetch="select">
        <key>
            <column name="typl_play_id" not-null="true" />
        </key>
        <one-to-many class="de.tt.treg.server.domain.PlayerCompetition" />
    </set>
</class>
```

**PlayerCompetition (Typeperplayer)**

```
<hibernate-mapping package="de.tt.treg.server.domain">
<class name="PlayerCompetition" table="typeperplayer">
    <composite-id name="playerCompetitionPk"
            class="PlayerCompetitionPk">
        <key-property name="id" column="Typl_Play_Id"
            type="java.lang.Integer" />
        <key-property name="id" column="Typl_Type_Id"
            type="java.lang.Integer" />
    </composite-id>
    <property name="paid" type="java.lang.Integer">
        <column name="Typl_Paid" length="10" not-null="false" unique="false" />
    </property>
    <many-to-one name="player" class="Player" insert="false" update="false"/>
    <many-to-one name="competition" class="Competition" insert="false" update="false"/>
</class>
```

**Competition (Type):**

```
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="de.tt.treg.server.domain.Competition" table="type">
    <id name="id" type="java.lang.Integer">
        <column name="Type_ID" />
        <generator class="identity" />
    </id>
    <property name="name" type="string">
        <column name="Type_Name" length="255" not-null="false" unique="false" />
    </property>
     <set name="players" table="typeperplayer"
            inverse="false" lazy="true" fetch="select">
        <key>
            <column name="Type_Id" not-null="true" />
        </key>
        <one-to-many class="de.tt.treg.server.domain.PlayerCompetition" />
    </set>

</class>
```

Additionally here are my classes:

```
public class Player{

private int id;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private Set<PlayerCompetition> competitions = new HashSet<PlayerCompetition>();

public Player() {
}

public Player(String firstName, String lastName,
        Set<PlayerCompetition> competitions) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.competitions = competitions;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

public Set<PlayerCompetition> getCompetitions() {
    return competitions;
}

public void setCompetitions(Set<PlayerCompetition> competitions) {
    this.competitions = competitions;
}

}

public class PlayerCompetition {
private int id;
private int paid;
private PlayerCompetitionPk playerCompetitionPk;

public PlayerCompetition() {

}

public PlayerCompetition(int id, int paid,
        PlayerCompetitionPk competitionPk) {
    super();
    this.id = id;
    this.paid = paid;
    this.playerCompetitionPk = competitionPk;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public int getPaid() {
    return paid;
}

public void setPaid(int paid) {
    this.paid = paid;
}

public PlayerCompetitionPk getPlayerCompetitionPk() {
    return playerCompetitionPk;
}

public void setPlayerCompetitionPk(PlayerCompetitionPk playerCompetitionPk) {
    this.playerCompetitionPk = playerCompetitionPk;
}

public Player getPlayer() {
    return getPlayerCompetitionPk().getPlayer();
}

public void setPlayer(Player player) {
    getPlayerCompetitionPk().setPlayer(player);
}

public Competition getCompetition() {
    return getPlayerCompetitionPk().getCompetition();
}

public void setCompetition(Competition competition) {
    getPlayerCompetitionPk().setCompetition(competition);
}
```

}

```
public class PlayerCompetitionPk {

private int id;
private Player player;
private Competition competition;

public PlayerCompetitionPk() {

}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public Player getPlayer() {
    return player;
}

public void setPlayer(Player player) {
    this.player = player;
}

public Competition getCompetition() {
    return competition;
}

public void setCompetition(Competition competition) {
    this.competition = competition;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
```

}

```
public class Competition {

private int id;

private String name;


private Set<PlayerCompetition> players;

public Competition() {
}

public Competition(int id, String name) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public Set<PlayerCompetition> getPlayers() {
    return players;
}

public void setPlayers(Set<PlayerCompetition> players) {
    this.players = players;
}
```

}

I hope somebody can help me. If you need some additional information, you will get it ;-). Thank you.

Here is the generated sql statement:
select player0_.Play_ID as Play1_1_2_, player0_.Play_Club_ID as Play2_1_2_, player0_.Play_User_ID as Play3_1_2_, player0_.Play_FirstName as Play4_1_2_, player0_.Play_LastName as Play5_1_2_, player0_.Play_BirthDate as Play6_1_2_, team1_.Club_ID as Club1_0_0_, team1_.Club_Name as Club2_0_0_, team1_.Club_ShortName as Club3_0_0_, team1_.Club_Verband as Club4_0_0_, user2_.User_ID as User1_4_1_, user2_.User_Name as User2_4_1_, user2_.User_Passwort as User3_4_1_, user2_.User_RegisterDate as User4_4_1_ from player player0_ inner join club team1_ on player0_.Play_Club_ID=team1_.Club_ID inner join user user2_ on player0_.Play_User_ID=user2_.User_ID where player0_.Play_ID=?

In this statement are two joins with the other tables club and users. But there is no join with via typeperplayer.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to not directly map the player and type entities with a many-to-many relation, but instead have an intermediate entity playertype which you connect with one-to-many to both player and type.

That way you can use additional columns as properties on the playertype entity.

```
player <1-*> playertype <*-1> type
```

Edit:
Here's a nice example from mkyong

http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-many-to-many-example-join-table-extra-column-annotation/

Comment: i already tried this. You can see a one-to-many relation in player.hbm to typeperplayer and also a one-to-many relation between competition and typeperplayer. But where is the mistake i didnt find it and i already followed the given tutorial.

Comment: To be honest I am null with xml mapping. Thats why I did not realize you followed that approach already ;) one thing i saw is that you are not using the full class name in the many-to-one mappings of the playercompetition. Do you get an error during sessionfactory creation? Or what is not working?

Comment: no there is no error. If i request a player by id i get null as result. I dont have the full name because I used package name in this xml. This is not the problem. I think it is more in the many-to-one and in the composite elements, but i dont understand the problem.

Comment: Can you post the select created by hibernate during a load? Log key should be org.hibernate.SQL=debug

Comment: i added the statement in my original post.